# Unescape json string in python

Tags: json, python-2.7

I am getting the following string from a log file and I want to remove the backslashes from the string.

**String from file:**

This is the exact string fro the log file, except for some sensitive info replaced with dummy values.

```
2017-08-17 17:29:49.249  ERROR org.foo.bar.logging.ApplicationLogger - APIError={"input":"{\"requestBody\":\"{\\\"request\\\":{\\\"drequests\\\":{\\\"items\\\":[{\\\"Description\\\":\\\"I would like to add an additional card.\\\",\\\"Fields\\\":{\\\"Field\\\":[{\\\"FieldName\\\":\\\"Severity\\\",\\\"FieldValue\\\":\\\"4\\\"},{\\\"FieldName\\\":\\\"Contact\\\",\\\"FieldValue\\\":\\\"Phone\\\"},{\\\"FieldName\\\":\\\"CallbackNumber\\\",\\\"FieldValue\\\":\\\"1 (123) 123456\\\"},{\\\"FieldName\\\":\\\"Version\\\",\\\"FieldValue\\\":\\\"11.1\\\"},{\\\"FieldName\\\":\\\"Language\\\",\\\"FieldValue\\\":\\\"English\\\"}]},\\\"Product\\\":\\\"Visa\\\",\\\"Subject\\\":\\\"Adding an addition card\\\",\\\"Serial_Number\\\":\\\"123456789\\\"}]},\\\"Email\\\":\\\"someone@gmail.com\\\",\\\"First_Name\\\":\\\"Foo\\\",\\\"Last_Name\\\":\\\"Bar\\\"}}\"}"}
```

**Python code**

```
str = read_from_file()
print str.replace('\\"', '"')
```

I tried this line of code but it is not having any effect. How can I get rid of backslahses from the json string?

**EDIT**

I tried the solution of recursively doing json.loads but that didn't remove the backslashes.

Just to give a better context - I am not processing this json string as JSON, instead I am only writing this to another file so it is more readable to another human. Below is my complete code.

```
import re
import json
from tailf import tailf


def parseRecursive(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, str):
        try:  # see whether it is JSON: if so, parse it
            obj = json.loads(obj)
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            pass  # if not, leave it like it is
        if isinstance(obj, dict):  # perform recursion
            for prop, val in obj.items():
                obj[prop] = parseRecursive(val)
    return obj


for line in tailf("/var/log/test.log"):
    m = re.search('([\d\-:\s]+).*ERROR.*APIError=(.*)', line)
    if m is None:
        print "No match"
    else:
        print m.group(1)
        print parseRecursive(m.group(2));
```

When I run this script it will print the string and the backslashes are not removed at all also notice two `u'` character in the beginning of the second line.

**Output**

```
2017-08-17 17:29:49
{u'input': u'{"requestBody":"{\\"request\\":{\\"drequests\\":{\\"items\\":[{\\"Description\\":\\"I would like to add an additional card.\\",\\"Fields\\":{\\"Field\\":[{\\"FieldName\\":\\"Severity\\",\\"FieldValue\\":\\"4\\"},{\\"FieldName\\":\\"Contact\\",\\"FieldValue\\":\\"Phone\\"},{\\"FieldName\\":\\"CallbackNumber\\",\\"FieldValue\\":\\"1 (123) 123456\\"},{\\"FieldName\\":\\"Version\\",\\"FieldValue\\":\\"11.1\\"},{\\"FieldName\\":\\"Language\\",\\"FieldValue\\":\\"English\\"}]},\\"Product\\":\\"Visa\\",\\"Subject\\":\\"Adding an addition card\\",\\"Serial_Number\\":\\"123456789\\"}]},\\"Email\\":\\"someone@gmail.com\\",\\"First_Name\\":\\"Foo\\",\\"Last_Name\\":\\"Bar\\"}}"}'}
```

**UPDATE**

**It was a silly mistake!** I had to type case the oobject to string and then call replace function. The below code worked.

```
import re
from tailf import tailf

for line in tailf("/var/log/test.log"):
    m = re.search('([\d\-:\s]+).*ERROR.*APIError=(.*)', line)
    if m is None:
        print "No match"
    else:
        print m.group(1)
        encodedString = m.group(2) + ''
        print str(encodedString).replace('\\', '')
```

Comment: This seems to work in my console. What are you seeing? However this replacement does not produce a valid json anyway.

Comment: This was just an example, I am reading the content from file but it is not working. I have updated my snippet.

Comment: This is the response I'm getting: `{"input":"{"requestBody":"{"request":{"drequests":{"items":[{"Description":"I would like to add an additional card.","Fields":{"Field":[{"FieldName":"Severity","FieldValue":"4"},{"FieldName":"Contact","FieldValue":"Phone"},{"FieldName":"CallbackNumber","FieldValue":"1 (123) 123456"},{"FieldName":"Version","FieldValue":"11.1"},{"FieldName":"Language","FieldValue":"English"}]},"Product":"Visa","Subject":"Adding an addition card","Serial_Number":"123456789"}]},"Email":"someone@gmail.com","First_Name":"Foo","Last_Name":"Bar"}}"}"}`

What do you get? any error?

Comment: The JSON will become invalid if you remove the backslashes. Apparently the JSON represents an object of which the properties have string values that themselves are JSON encoded, ...etc. So the escapes are needed for the overall JSON to be valid.

Comment: My code extracts the json string from the log message and writes it into another file, so while writing to another file I want to remove the backslashes.

Comment: @AvihooMamka I didn't get any error, but the backslashes didn't get removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON represented in the string needs the backslashes, as apparently the represented object has property values that themselves are JSON encoded strings. These embedded strings need their double quotes to be escaped. Remove them would make the overall JSON invalid.

What you may need is to resolve the embedded JSON strings to the objects they represent. For this you would best use a recursive function that uses the `json.loads` method to parse each of the nested JSONs.

NB: it is not a good idea to use the name `str` for your data, as that is the name of the Python data type.

Here is suggested solution:

```
import json
import re

def parseRecursive(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, basestring):
        try: # see whether it is JSON: if so, parse it
            obj = json.loads(obj)
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            pass # if not, leave it like it is
        if isinstance(obj, dict): # perform recursion
            for prop, val in obj.items():
                obj[prop] = parseRecursive(val)
    return obj

# Sample Input
msg = r'2017-08-17 17:29:49.249  ERROR org.foo.bar.logging.ApplicationLogger - APIError={"input":"{\"requestBody\":\"{\\\"request\\\":{\\\"drequests\\\":{\\\"items\\\":[{\\\"Description\\\":\\\"I would like to add an additional card.\\\",\\\"Fields\\\":{\\\"Field\\\":[{\\\"FieldName\\\":\\\"Severity\\\",\\\"FieldValue\\\":\\\"4\\\"},{\\\"FieldName\\\":\\\"Contact\\\",\\\"FieldValue\\\":\\\"Phone\\\"},{\\\"FieldName\\\":\\\"CallbackNumber\\\",\\\"FieldValue\\\":\\\"1 (123) 123456\\\"},{\\\"FieldName\\\":\\\"Version\\\",\\\"FieldValue\\\":\\\"11.1\\\"},{\\\"FieldName\\\":\\\"Language\\\",\\\"FieldValue\\\":\\\"English\\\"}]},\\\"Product\\\":\\\"Visa\\\",\\\"Subject\\\":\\\"Adding an addition card\\\",\\\"Serial_Number\\\":\\\"123456789\\\"}]},\\\"Email\\\":\\\"someone@gmail.com\\\",\\\"First_Name\\\":\\\"Foo\\\",\\\"Last_Name\\\":\\\"Bar\\\"}}\"}"}'

# Extract json part: take "{ ... }" from message string
match = re.search(r"\{.*\}", msg)
if match:
    # parse nested JSON
    obj = parseRecursive(match.group(0))
    print obj
```

See it run on [repl.int](https://repl.it/FpJA/6). Note that the output `obj` is a `dict`. The prefixed `u` in the output just means that the keys are unicode strings. But you can access any nested value in it, like:

```
print obj['input']['requestBody']['request']['Email']
```

Output:

> someone@gmail.com

Comment: DIdn't work. I will add my complete code in the question, may be I am missing something.

Comment: It worked here: https://repl.it/HbaA/12. I also want to point out that simply replacing the backslashes yields a string that is not valid JSON.

Comment: Ah, I see you are on Pyhton 2.7. The data type for string is called `basestring` then instead of `str`. See: https://repl.it/FpJA/6

Comment: Right! I am new to Python and most people suggested to go with 2.7. Thanks!

Comment: Accepted your answer because this is also a solution.